# The name 'Total Cost' doesnt exist in the current context

Tags: c#

I have created the Return class with a new instance of Return

But im getting an error saying Totalcost doesnt exist in the current context

The variable TotalCost is held in another class called Cost

So how do I get the contents held in TotalCost in the Cost class into Return class for use with the output

```
public void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    //Write all details to a text file that is created on the desktop
    Return newTextFile = new Return();   
    {
        txtTotalCost.Text = ("£" + TotalCost.ToString());
    }

    newTextFile.EventDetailsFile = "C:\\AllUsers\\User\\Desktop\\EventDetails.txt";
    System.IO.StreamWriter objWriter;

    objWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(newTextFile.EventDetailsFile);

    objWriter.Write("Event Type:" + EventList.SelectedItem + "\n");
    objWriter.Write("Event Name:" + txtEventName.Text + "\n");
    objWriter.Write("Customer Name:" + txtName.Text + "\n");
    objWriter.Write("Customer Address:" + txtAddress.Text + "\n");
    objWriter.Write("Event Start Date:" +txtStart.Text + "\n");
    objWriter.Write("Event End Date:" + txtEnd.Text + "\n");
    objWriter.Write("Number of People Attending:" + txtPeople.Text + "\n");
    objWriter.Write("Total Event Cost: £" + TotalCost);
    objWriter.Close();

    MessageBox.Show("The text file has been Created");
}
```

The code in class cost is as follows

```
class Cost
{
    public int TotalCost;
    public int Event;
    public int personalEvent;
    public int organisationalEvent;
}
```

Comment: Not enough...*context* has been supplied for us to see the problem.  Where is `txtTotalCost` declared?

Comment: txtTotalCost is the text box on the form

Comment: `txtTotalCost.Text = ("£" + TotalCost.ToString());` - what is `TotalCost` ?

Comment: If `TotalCost` is in another class then you need to access it through an instance of that other class.

Comment: @ Arghya C TotalCost is an amount that is held in that variable in the cost class i now need to use it within the return class for displaying the final costing

Comment: Since your class or the field is not static (from the code you provided) you need an instance of the `Cost` class that has the value, to access `TotalCost`, something like `costObj.TotalCost`.

Answer (score 0):

> So how do I get the contents held in TotalCost in the EventCost?

If `EventCost` is not a static class, you should have an object of type `EventCost`, let's call it `enentCost`. Then you can just get the `EventCost` as

```
eventCost.TotalCost
```

Otherwise, if `EventCost` is a static class, which at least to me it doesn't make any sense, you could get the `EventCost` as

```
EventCost.TotalCost
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, from your code I can see that you need an instance of the class Cost, here:

```
public void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    var cost = new Cost();
```

Also, you need to check that your class namespace is reachable from the method btnCalculate_Click, example is that the class Cost is in the namespace Project.Totals, here some code:

```
using Project.Totals;

public void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    var cost = new Cost();
```